# What is happening when my uncommitted changes temporarily disappear from magit?

Tags: magit

More then once when I have been reviewing changes to be committed in magit, the pending changes have unexpectedly disappeared from the status buffer. I'm pretty sure it's because I am accidentally hitting some key, but I have no idea which key. It is as if I told magit to ignore all uncommitted changes. If I close out of emacs completely, open the appropriate file, and run `magit-status`, then the uncommitted changes will have returned as expected and I can go ahead an commit them.

What key or function might be causing saved, uncommitted changes to be temporarily hidden or ignored like that? If I do it again, what else can I try next time, instead of closing emacs, that might make them visible again?

Comment: I think if you hit `TAB` on the section header (e.g. Unstaged Changes) that collapses the section - maybe you are doing that?

Comment: Ah ha, I bet you're right, @verdammelt. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @brain-z ask and ye shall receive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> while on a section header (e.g. *Unstaged Changes* or *Untracked Files*) collapses that section. Hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> again expands the section again.

I have done this several times since some part of my brain thinks tabbing between the sections is a thing one can do (but my brain is wrong in this case).

Comment: Don't be too hard in your brain. TAB is a highly overloaded key in the world of user interfaces, and it's easy to get it mixed up.

Comment: Yeah, it is probably more of a case of my fingers doing something on their own. Lots of muscle memory. When telling someone how to do something in Emacs I usually have to do it because *I* don't know it my *fingers* do.